# Best way to count occurrences in a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with some key values occurring in one or more columns. Each value can occur zero or more times in each row. How do I efficiently calculate number of occurrences of each value in the entire table?

example:

```
c1  | c2  | c3
----+-----+-----
A . | B . | C
A . | C . | D
E . | C . | B
D . | D . | A
C . | B . | B
```

desired result:

```
A 3
B 4
C 4
D 3
E 1
```

for reference, table has 6 columns, 50K rows, and 2000 distinct values scattered across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to select all the values into a union, then count:

something like:

```sql
SELECT data, count(*) FROM (
SELECT col1 as data FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT col2 as data FROM table
...
) GROUP BY data
```

Comment: nice and clean, and i'm not able to find a faster solution. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a lateral join:

```
select col, count(*)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (col1), (col2), (col3)) v(col)
group by col;
```

This is best because the source table only has to be scanned once, rather than once for each column.

Comment: gordon, thanks for the answer, i was hoping something like this would be faster than pivoting/unwinding table into a single column. i ran both approaches, yours ran in about 290ms, @Slawomir's version ran in 175ms. so union-ing somehow runs much faster; not sure if that's related to my data, though.

Comment: @ikcodez . . . Interesting.  Although web-based databases are not a good way to do timings, the timing here (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3248e8caf9d85f22acc5337a9862694c) are consistent with `union all` being faster.  I find that surprising, but it seems to be a real phenomenon.  I wonder if anyone knows why.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . Do you know why `union all` appears to be faster than a lateral join?  It seems counterintuitive to me.

Comment: The query planner is doing its job, and knows to scan through the table only once on both cases. The timing differences are in the same ballpark.

Comment: @SlawomirChodnicki . . . Actually, `union all` seems consistently faster.  And, it is cool if Postgres's query planner does only read the table once.

Comment: The difference in performance could change once the table is larger than available  buffer/disk-cache space.

Comment: @wildplasser . . . I could see that.  Or if transactions slowed down the read of the table.  However, I am befuddled on why the `union all` is **faster**.  I can see how comparable can be achieved with optimization, but there appears to be an overhead for the lateral joins that I don't understand.